# How to use enum to determine a conditional typescript return value?

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to determine a conditional type by using an enum, why isn't this working? I think if I remove the layer of `value`, it would work, but really curious why adding `value` here messes up the lookup.

```
// color all sedan -> string, suv -> hexadecimal
enum CarType {
  Sedan, SUV
}

type ColorLookup<T extends CarType> = T extends CarType.Sedan ? string : number


type CarColor = Record<CarType, {color: ColorLookup<CarType>}>


const data = {
  [CarType.Sedan]: { value: "red" },
  [CarType.SUV]: { value: 123123 }
}

const select = <T extends CarType>(type: T) => {
  return data[type].value
}

// For some reason this keeps telling me `string | number`
var a: string = select(CarType.Sedan)
var b: number = select(CarType.SUV)
```

Comment: I see neither `CarColor` nor `ColorLookup` being used in your example, and so I will ignore these in my answer.  That means this question has to do with generic property lookups and nothing to do with conditional types.

Answer (score 1):

When you access properties or call methods on values of an as-yet unspecified [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type, the compiler tends to eagerly evaluate the generic by first widening it to its [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints).  (See [this comment in microsoft/TypeScript#33181](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33181#issuecomment-526916194) for a description of this process.)

In the following code:

```
const select = <T extends CarType>(type: T) => {
  return data[type].value
}
```

the type `data[type]` is generic, and inferred to be of type `(typeof data)[T]`.  But then when you index into it with the `value` property, the compiler first widens `T` to its constraint, `CarType`.  So `data[type].value` is evaluated as `(typeof data)[CarType]["value"]`, which is `string | number`.

This isn't *wrong*, but it's not useful for your purposes.

---

If you want to prevent this from happening you can [annotate](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) a variable to be the analogous generic type, and then return that:

```
const select = <T extends CarType>(type: T) => {
    const dataTypeValue: (typeof data)[T]["value"] = data[type].value
    return dataTypeValue;
}
```

The compiler has now been convinced not to prematurely widen to a specific type.  So now the type of `select` is seen as

```
const select: <T extends CarType>(type: T) => {
    0: {
        value: string;
    };
    1: {
        value: number;
    };
}[T]["value"]
```

which behaves as you intend when `T` is specified with either `CarType.Sedan` or `CarType.SUV`:

```
var a: string = select(CarType.Sedan); // okay
var b: number = select(CarType.SUV); // okay
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.2#code/PTAEGMHsBtIJ1AQ2tUBnApgE0QO1ALQB86ALnAJa4DmANOgK4BuhJAFhgB6JYbgUBbZACgMuBgNABhRHAAqATwAOGUAG9hoLaADK2PPR0BVAGrCAvsOFRcaUqBylEoALzrN2gNoz5yjADo9HFwAXQAudVAmZAYMCIAiOGx40HNaDy1vWUUVQNNwyOjoWIiARgAmAGYKytSLKxs7dAxoPns3AB45UC5SMSw0aWy-IgAKUj8IuQBKVxINbQhIW3tHRByMExi40HG-SAAzB0Qnac85EM94otj4kNdjp08JlRD-G4wM0CTSBjh8NYbLbFDAAbnqwmAAColitmq1wKQIl0epw+rgBkNfCoxi8djM5u5FgAGCILRbaD4ROyUGjgxbmenaUpkr6LKmgcQCABGGDgTK0jIs50u122d1AUOAVmiCEQ1PIVGoD0wCNIox8G0C+lw01BoBAoEgAGtEAphLLQNyIlzeQg3Kq2hrhrljCY9QawCazUA)